# Unreal Engine 4.27 plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, unreal-engine4

Please I need help. I am working on a plugin and want it to store drag-and-dropped assets into an array. I created a struct (FMyStruct) that will save the assets and made a shared pointer of FMyStruct, then made it a type name:

```
struct FMyStruct
{
    UStaticMesh* Mesh;

    FMyStruct(UStaticMesh* InAsset);

    bool operator == (const FMyStruct& Other) const
    {
        return Mesh == Other.Mesh;
    }
};
typedef TSharedPtr<FMyStruct> FMyStructPtr;
```

I made an array of this pointer:

`TArray<FMyStructPtr> MySrtuctPtrArray;`

But when I use any function with MySrtuctPtrArray, for example MySrtuctPtrArray.Empty(), I receive and error saying

**Exception thrown: read access violation.**

**[Raw View]    0x00000000000001d0 {AllocatorInstance={Data=??? } ArrayNum=??? ArrayMax=??? }** **TArray<TSharedPtr<FMyStruct,0>,TSizedDefaultAllocator<32>>***

Please I really don't know how to solve this.

**EDIT**
The initialization is:

```
FMyStruct::FMyStruct(UStaticMesh* InAsset)
    : Mesh(InAsset)
{
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing that pointer? Have you implemented the constructor?

Comment: Do you use `MakeShared` to allocate it? Also, FYI, it won't hold a reference to `Mesh`, so it might be GC'ed and the pointer will dangle. You should either derive your class from `UObject` and mark `Mesh` as `UPROPERTY` or derive it from `FGCObject` and override `AddReferencedObjects`

Comment: Yes, I have initialized the struct.

Comment: The pointer is initialized out of the struct and class (i.e. Globally in the header file).

Comment: After doing some research, I found out the same was done in the engine source code for the foliage. When you drop static meshes in the drop zone, an array of shared pointers to the struct FFoliageUIInfo is created in the FoliageEdMode class. Guess what, what I did was the same as in the source code but for some reason, it does not work.